# Full-text search migration 2005 -> 2012 (.ndf file?)

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, migration

So I'm trying to figure out the details for migrating from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2012.

1. I tried to do restore and backup of a DB from 2005 to 2012. This worked well and for the text search catalog created a .ndf file.
2. I tried to detach and attach a DB from 2005 to 2012, this also seemed to work fine including the text search but I'm wondering where's the catalog files on the file system because I don't see a .ndf file or a dedicated folder for text search catalog (the way we used to have in versions prior to 2008)?

(PS. I atttached only .mdf and .ldf files, not sure how to attach a specific text search catalog file because it's multiple files)

I might have missed something but any suggestions will be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of things to consider :

backup and restore is the safest option that you can use for migration from SQL 2005 to 2012.

Refer [here](http://mssqlfun.com/2012/09/21/upgrade-sql-server-2005-full-text-catalog-to-sql-server-2012-by-detach-attach-part-2-of-2/) for more details of what you are experiencing.

Full text has undergone major chance in 2008 and up.

from [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142490.aspx),

**Attaching a SQL Server 2005 Database to SQL Server 2012**

In SQL Server 2008 and later versions, a full-text catalog is a logical concept that refers to a group of full-text indexes. The full-text catalog is a virtual object that does not belong to any filegroup. However, **when you attach a SQL Server 2005 database that contains full-text catalog files onto a SQL Server 2012 server instance, the catalog files are attached from their previous location along with the other database files, the same as in SQL Server 2005.**

The state of each attached full-text catalog on SQL Server 2012 is the same as when the database was detached from SQL Server 2005. If any full-text index population was suspended by the detach operation, the population is resumed on SQL Server 2012, and the full-text index becomes available for full-text search.

**If SQL Server 2012 cannot find a full-text catalog file or if the full-text file was moved during the attach operation without specifying a new location, the behavior depends on the selected full-text upgrade option. If the full-text upgrade option is Import or Rebuild, the attached full-text catalog is rebuilt. If the full-text upgrade option is Reset, the attached full-text catalog is reset.**

EDIT:

You can attach the detached database along with the fulltext catalog using Create database ... FOR ATTACH.

```
-- Physically move the full text catalog to the new location.
--Attach the AdventureWorks database and specify the new location of the full-text catalog.
CREATE DATABASE AdventureWorks ON 
    (FILENAME = 'D:\...\Data\AdventureWorks_Data.mdf'), 
    (FILENAME = 'D:\...\log\AdventureWorks_log.ldf'),
    (FILENAME = 'D:\myFTCatalogs\AdvWksFtCat')
FOR ATTACH;
GO
```

Comment: Kin: thanks for your answer, appreciate it. One last doubt I still have is, the Text search catalog has a bunch of files in a folder called FTData, now I'm not sure how to attach those files. But I do agree backup and restore sounds like a better option. But we were thinking if we could avoid that as we have bunch of databases and it could take a while to do backup restores instead of detach/attach.

Comment: thank you for appending the answer to my question in previous comment!